# Difference between two records from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with a table as follow:

```
id     date        time    value 
9014 2014-09-07 17:01:01 2571385 
9015 2014-09-07 18:01:01 2571391
```

I would like to know how to insert a new column (called difference) with the difference of the value of two consecutive rows 
Example:

```
id date time value difference
9014 2014-09-07 17:01:01 2571385 5
9015 2014-09-07 18:01:01 2571391 6
```

and so on  ( 5 corresponding to 2571385 - 2571380 and 6 corresponding to 2571391 - 2571385 )

My table is automattically populated via a cron every 60 minutes

Should it be done via a PHP script or via a SQL request ?
As I am a beginner, some help will be needed .....if someone can write the script or request (mysql database = Conso, and table is Consommation)

Comment: for future inserts use a insert trigger to retrieve the value of the last entry order by id and get the difference to the newly inserted value

Comment: INSERT INTO Consommation(date,time,value,diff) values ('','',2571391, (select 2571391 - value from Consommation where ID = MAX(id) ))

Answer (score 0):

it is something like:

```
update t as a left join t as b on a.id=b.id+1 set a.difference=b.value-a.value;
```

where the table is named 't'

Comment: you could create a trigger in mysql to run this on table insert.